# allow negative number input fancy tree table

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I use fancytree ExTable where I bind one column to text input where I can insert numbers. However it doesn't allow me to input `-`(negative) sign, or can not use 'backspace' key to delete character, there must be some validation rule I missed somewhere.

here is the sameple code:

```
$("#treetable").fancytree({
   extensions: ["table"],
   checkbox: true,
   table: {
     indentation:20,
     nodeColumnIdx: 1,
     checkboxColumnIdx: 0
   },
   source : {
     url: 'mytest.php'
   },
   renderColumns: function(event, data) {
     var node = data.node
     ....
     $tdList.eq(5).html("<input type='number' name='test_field'>");
  });
```

I tried both `type='number'` and `type='text'`, they both not working.

Comment: It seems to work here: http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-multi-ext.html

Comment: It seems `jquery.fancytree.edit.js` is required, otherwise the behavior is as I described.